# I need to create a deep link for google reviews using place id in the link formula

Tags: deep-linking

I need to create a deep link for google reviews using place id in the link formula, and the link to  direct anyone who use it to google maps application

I tried to google it and tried other formulas posted by google for other functions but it didn’t work